# Android Camera Intent and Geotag

Tags: android, camera

Programmatically I turn on the GPS to get lat/lon and I want to use default android camera `Intent` to take geotagged photos.

Is there any extra param to pass to the default image capture `Intent` to enable geotag?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem simply by getting the image and later programmatically editing the exif datas of the image.